# Max of two ObservableDoubleValue as an ObservableDoubleValue

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, javafx-8

Given `ObservableDoubleValue a` and `ObservableDoubleValue b`, I can get their maximum like this:

```
NumberBinding m = Bindings.max(a,b);
```

What is the simplest way to get it as a `DoubleBinding` (or even just an `ObservableDoubleValue`) rather than a `NumberBinding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bindings.max` will already return an instance of `DoubleBinding` when you call it with one of the parameters being an `ObservableDoubleValue`.

Therefore, if you are sure that you're in this case, you can just cast the result to a `DoubleBinding`.

```
DoubleBinding max = (DoubleBinding) Bindings.max(a,b);
```

More specifically, the `NumberBinding` returned is:

- `DoubleBinding` if one of the argument is a `ObservableDoubleValue`.
- else `FloatBinding` if one of the argument is a `ObservableFloatValue`.
- else `LongBinding` if one of the argument is a `ObservableLongValue`.
- else `IntegerBinding`.

This is documented in [`NumberExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpression.html) Javadoc:

> This API allows to mix types when defining arithmetic operations. The type of the result is defined by the same rules as in the Java Language.
>
> - If one of the operands is a double, the result is a double.
> - If not and one of the operands is a float, the result is a float.
> - If not and one of the operands is a long, the result is a long.
> - The result is an integer otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own binding:

```
DoubleProperty a = ...
DoubleProperty b = ...
DoubleBinding maxBinding= new DoubleBinding() {

     {
         super.bind(a, b);
     }

     @Override
     protected double computeValue() {
         return Math.max(a.doubleValue(), b.doubleValue());
     }

     @Override
     public void dispose() {
         super.unbind(a, b);
     }
 };
```

See also the JavaDoc of [DoubleBinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleBinding.html).